# Can we use Espresso for external applications?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

Is there a way out that i can perform actions using espresso once i leave my application to some external application?

I am opening android image picker and want to select an image from the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is not possible with Espresso. You will get a SecurityException, if you send events to any window controlled by a different user id.

Here are a few things you could try:

- create a custom AOSP build and disable the security checks
- for API 16+ you can use uiautomator tests instead of instrumentation tests
- on API 18+ you can use instrumentation.getUIAutomation()